# Pass a Styled Component as a prop in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm using styled-components for all of my styling and would like to know how I can pass a style through from my parent component footer.jsx to my re-usable child component contact as a prop.

I've tried a few different ways, passing a string through as a prop and then passing that into a styled component in contact to update the `background-image{this.props.icon}` but this doesn't work and the current way I've tried doesn't render anything as well.

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kg0-scl1gRf4UTOaK-Y

Footer.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Contact from '../../molecules/Contact'

const Icon1 = styled.span`
  margin-top:8.333333px;
  background:url(icon1.png);
  width:25px; 
  height:25px;
  `
const Icon2 = styled.span`
  margin-top:8.333333px;
  background:url(icon2.png);
  width:25px; 
  height:25px;
  `
export default class MainFooter extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
         <Contact icon={<Icon1 />} />
         <Contact icon={<Icon2 />} />
      </Wrapper>
    )
   }
  }
```

contact.jsx

```
export default class Contact extends React.Component {
 return (
  <A href="/">
    <Wrapper>
      <ColLeft> {this.props.icon}</ColLeft>
    </Wrapper>
  </A>
  )
}
```

}

Comment: To improve your chances of getting good answers, please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX, loading external libs (via a CDN), etc.; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wbpackbin all correct, you just need to add `display: block` to your spans. In your variant you have two spans with `height: 0`.
See screenshot http://prntscr.com/enzkiw